# Add Subscribe and Download feature to Blogger

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I have my blog [www.webspeaks.in](http://www.webspeaks.in) which is on blogger (unfortunately I think). I provide files to be downloaded by my readers. I want that **only** the **visitors who are subscribed** to my blog can download the files. Is there any widget or tool available for this functionality.

Comment: @cad I think wordpress is the best tool for blogging. Blogger stands nowhere in front of wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for answer... I was wondering why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Blogger doesn't support that but as a workaround you can try:

> Upload documents online using google drive with security as "only
>   people with link" and show link in a section of your blog that
>   requires a visitor to be subscribed. They might still email link to
>   their friends, but maybe is enough for you.

Comment: thanks for this. But I can implement this with PHP as I provide downloads on subdomain of my blog (which runs on PHP). It will be nice if you can provide the PHP code.

Comment: I am unable to find the exact steps to do it. Can you provide the exact steps?

Comment: Create a document in Google Drive, click blue share button (upper right). In the popup, under "Who has access" it should say private. Click change and choose "Anyone with the link".